# Excel VBA: Error handling only works for one pass

Tags: vba, loops, excel, error-handling

I have searched many sources to try and fix my problem, however I have had no success. I am a beginner at VBA, so my code will seem very messy most likely. For the purpose of asking the question I will try and keep the info in the sheets to a minimum

I have two sheets, 'Data' and 'Raw Numbers'.
Data contains columns headed "Property" and "Phone Number", but only "Property" has data in it.
Raw Numbers contains the same columns, however it is missing some of the "Property" values, as it only contains a certain number of phone numbers associated with those properties.

DATA SHEET:
Property . . . . Number
1 Ada St
2 Ada St
3 Ada St
4 Ada St
5 Ada St
6 Ada St

RAW NUMBERS SHEET:
Property . . . . Number
1 Ada St . . . . 12345678
2 Ada St . . . . 12356322
5 Ada St . . . . 12551122
6 Ada St . . . . 12212112

I have a code that imports the numbers into the Data sheet automatically, however once it reaches 3 Ada St, it returns an Error (400) because there is no 3 Ada St on Raw Numbers. I included an error handler, however it only works once before returning the error again.
Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Button_Click()
Worksheets("Data").Range("B4").Select  'B4 is the Number column in the data sheet
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) <> ""
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Numbers").Range("Numbers"), 2, False), "")

ErrorHandler:
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub
```

I wrote the code this way because I originally had it working with Functions rather than code, however that was too messy. The IfError function is in there because I want the cell to be blank if there is no number attached to the address. I tried converting this to part of the errorhandler, however it just ended up giving me an error.

Somebody please help me!! If you need any more information, I will gladly provide it. I will be watching this thread constantly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formula in the code and paste values after.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Numbers,2,FALSE),"""")"
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
```

**Untested...**

Comment: This didn't entirely work, however I ended up using a combination of a formula and this code.
I put formulas in the cells, and just added the "ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value" part into the button that populates the results. This allows me to instantly convert the cells to their value rather than the formula.

Thank you!! I hope I can find a proper fix however.
The problem I have now is, when I click my Clear button, it does not put the formula back in those cells. If I were to do this via code with my know-how, it would be extremely tedious, naming every single cell.

Comment: Found a solution! Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

functions shouldn't be too messy. A combination of `IFERROR` and `VLOOKUP` should work.

the formula would look something like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,RawData!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

In VBA, I would code something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim Result

On Error Resume Next
Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([A3], [RawData!A:B], 2, False)
If Err.Number = 1004 Then ' data not found, or some other formula error
    Result = ""
Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & "-" & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End If

[B3] = Result
End Sub
```

Comment: I had no problem doing it with formulas, however I will be doing other things with these values and need the cells to be filled with the text rather than the formula.

Comment: @LukeBeacon, Added VBA form of function - `[]` are used for quick and dirty `Range` references, they are equivalent to `Range("??")`